# Symfony - Besimple issue with a complex type

Tags: symfony, complextype, soapserver

I recently beginning to develop with symfony. I just create a soap server with besimple.

This is my code.

config.yml - Server

```
be_simple_soap:
    services:
        Gremios:
            namespace:     http://att/app_dev.php/ws/Gremios
            binding:       rpc-literal
            resource:      "@attBundle/Controller/GremioController.php"
            resource_type: annotation
```

Gremios Controller

```
class GremioController extends Controller{
     /**
     * @Route("/apiGremio/{id}")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Soap\Method("getGremio")
     * @Soap\Param("name", phpType = "int")
     * @Soap\Result(phpType = "att\Bundle\Entity\Atgremio")
     */
    public function apiGremioAction($id)
    {

        $gremio = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("attBundle:Atgremio")
                                      ->findById($id);
        return $gremio;
    }
}
```

Entity Atgremio

```
    namespace att\Bundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use BeSimple\SoapBundle\ServiceDefinition\Annotation as Soap;

    /**
     * Atgremio
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="AtGremio")
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @Soap\Alias("Gremio")
     */

class Atgremio
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @Soap\ComplexType("int", nillable=true)
     */
    private $id;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="desGremio", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
 * @Soap\ComplexType("string")
 */
private $desgremio;



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set desgremio
 *
 * @param string $desgremio
 * @return Atgremio
 */
public function setDesgremio($desgremio)
{
    $this->desgremio = $desgremio;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get desgremio
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDesgremio()
{
    return $this->desgremio;
}
}
```

config.yml Client

```
be_simple_soap:
      clients:
         GremioApi:     
            wsdl: "http://att/app_dev.php/ws/Gremios?wsdl"
```

Client Action in Controller

```
class PruebaController extends Controller
{ 
   /**
     * @Route("/gremioapp/{id}")
     * @Template
     */
    public function pruebaControllerAction($id) 
    {
        $client = $this->container->get('besimple.soap.client.gremioapi'); 
        $result = $client->getGremio($id);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

When i execute a client action, i get error 500. But, when execute a server action, no errors found. Equal when i see the wdsl generated

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://att/app_dev.php/ws/Gremios" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Gremios" targetNamespace="http://att/app_dev.php/ws/Gremios">
<portType name="GremiosPortType">
<operation name="getGremio">
<input message="tns:getGremioRequest"/>
<output message="tns:getGremioResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://att/app_dev.php/ws/Gremios">
<xsd:complexType name="Gremio">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="desgremio" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="getGremioRequest">
<part name="name" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
<message name="getGremioResponse">
<part name="return" type="tns:Gremio"/>
</message>
<service name="GremiosService">
<port name="GremiosPort" binding="tns:GremiosBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:5080/app_dev.php/ws/Gremios"/>
</port>
</service>
<binding name="GremiosBinding" type="tns:GremiosPortType">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
<operation name="getGremio">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://att/app_dev.php/ws/GremiosgetGremio"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://att/app_dev.php/ws/Gremios" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://att/app_dev.php/ws/Gremios" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
</definitions>
```

Tanks for a help

Comment: please check for any errors in `app/logs/prod.log` or `app/logs/dev.log`

Comment: thanks!! i checked the log and found the problem.